# A non-convex quadratically constrained quadratic program

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \beta^{T} A \beta\\ \text{subject to} & \beta^{T} C \beta=1\\ & \beta \geqslant 0\end{array}$$

where $A, C\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$ and $\beta \in  \mathbb{R}^{M}$. I saw in one paper that it could be solved via its semidefinite programming relaxation by adding an auxiliary variable $B \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ like this:

$\min_{\beta ,B}trace(AB)$

$s.t.trace(CB)=1$,

$\beta \geqslant 0$,

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \beta^{T}\\\\ 
 \beta& B
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$

where $\succeq 0$ means left matrix is positive semidefinite. I don't get how this is done, and besides, how to solve such a problem using any possible C/C++ software? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful if you cite the paper in which you saw something that you're asking a question about- we could provide a better answer if we knew where the question came from.

First, assume without loss of generality that $A$ and $C$ are symmetric matrices.  It's easy to take these quadratic forms and write them in terms of symmetric matrices.

I believe that this problem transformation requires that $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix- see below.

We'll begin with your second problem and show that it is equivalent to the original problem.  We begin with

$\min \mbox{tr}(AB) $

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(CB)=1$

$ \beta \geq 0 $

$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \beta^{T} \\\
\beta & B 
\end{array}
\right]
\succeq 0
$

By Schur's theorem, the constraint

$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \beta^{T} \\\
\beta & B 
\end{array}
\right]
\succeq 0
$

is equivalent to

$B \succeq \beta \beta^{T} $

Note that we've implicitly restricted $B$ to being a symmetric matrix.

Next, write $B$ as

$B= \beta \beta^{T} + LL^{T} $

where $L$ is the (slightly generalized) Cholesky factor of $B- \beta \beta^{T}$.  If $B-\beta \beta^{T}$ is singular, then $L$ would be singular or even $0$.

Then our problem is equivalent to

$\min \mbox{tr}( A ( \beta \beta^{T} + LL^{T} ) ) $

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(CB)=1$

$ \beta \geq 0 $

$ B=\beta \beta^{T} + LL^{T} $

By the property $\mbox{tr}(DEF)=\mbox{tr}(FDE)$, this problem is equivalent to

$\min \mbox{tr}(\beta^{T}A\beta + L^{T}AL) $

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(CB)=1$

$ \beta \geq 0 $

$ B=\beta \beta^{T} + LL^{T} $

Note that because $A \succeq 0$, $\mbox{tr}(L^{T}AL) \geq 0$ for all $L$, and the term is minimized when $L=0$.

Thus our problem is equivalent to:

$\min \mbox{tr}(\beta^{T}A\beta) $

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(CB)=1$

$ \beta \geq 0 $

$ B=\beta \beta^{T} $

Since $B=\beta \beta^{T}$, and by the cyclic property of $\mbox{tr}()$, this is equivalent to

$\min \mbox{tr}(\beta^{T}A\beta) $

subject to

$\beta^{T}C\beta=1$

$ \beta \geq 0 $

This was your original problem.

Comment: There are several software packages for solving such an SDP, including SDPA (written in C++) and CSDP (in C)

Comment: As I recall, you can also get to this formulation using the S-lemma.


Comment: On second thought, although approach I sketched out is sufficient to show that the SDP is a relaxation of the original problem, it's not enough to show that the relaxation is exact (I forgot to account for the $L^{T}CL$ term in the constraint.  I'm afraid that you need the machinery of the S-lemma to show that the relaxation is exact.  

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!$:-)$ I read it carefully and basically understand your proof. The paper I quote is *Yen-Yu Lin, Multiple Kernel Learning for Dimensionality Reduction*.In fact I need this relaxation to be exact, but I don't quite get what S-lemma is, Could you please show some links or pdfs? And how to use it to make the relaxation exact is also new to me.

Comment: See appendix B of "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe. 

Comment: The general result is that if you have a quadratically constrained quadratic programming problem with only one non-convex constraint, then you can formulate it exactly as an SDP.  That's why I believe that this relaxation will be exact in this case.  However, I haven't looked into this for several years, so the details escape me at the moment.  If I get a chance I'll try to sit down and work through the details.  

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Here I have some difficulty in transforming this SDP relaxation to the standard form of SDP which doesn't have inequality constraints in it, could you lend me some help? I read in the sdpa user guide that this could be done by adding some slack variables, after that the variable matrix X becomes $X=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \beta ^{T} &  & \\ 
 \beta& B &  & \\ 
 &  &  slack_{1}& \\ 
 &  &  & slack_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$. I guess some more constraints needs to be added to ensure that X has rest of its entries being zero, but that would be too complicated.

Comment: CSDP (and all of the other SDP solvers) support block diagonal matrices and also allow for blocks which are stricted to being block diagonal.

If $B$ is of size $N$ by $N$, then your X matrix will have one block of size $N+1$ by $N+1$, holding $B$, $\beta$, and the $1$.  You'll need one equality constraint to specify that this first element is 1.  

Your X matrix will also have a diagonal block of size $N$ to hold the slack variables.  There's no need for constraints to make those off diagonal elements 0.  

If you're using the MATLAB interface to CSDP, then you'd have K.s=N+1 and K.l=N.


Comment: Then it shall be easy, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to learn more about this subject, I'd suggest looking at "A survey of the S-Lemma" by Imre Polik and Tamas Terlaky, from SIAM Review, Vol 49, No. 3, p 371-418, 2007.  In particular, look at section 6 of the paper that discusses problems with rank limitations (you want your B matrix to be rank 1.)  After reviewing this paper and thinking about your problem a bit, I can't see how to apply the S-Lemma approach to your particular problem.  